# Webscraping using Nodejs - <ul> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a stock market web page for the titles of href links.
I don't get any output. I tried calling the class, id's,etc.
I see the  tag has a $0 assigned. I typed this in the console command line but it just showed the same thing.

I am trying to get the text "Bulk Deals" from the html. If I can figure how that's done, I can proceed.

Code:

```js
  var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var request = require('request');

    var url ="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nseindia/CMDailyReport";
    request(url, function(err, resp, body){
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     $(".regularitem .itemtitle").each(function(){
      var link = $(this);
      var text = link.text();
          var href = link.attr("href");

       console.log(text + href);
     
     });    

    });
```

```html
    <ul>
     <li xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" class="regularitem">
      <h4 class="itemtitle">
       <a href="http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/nseindia/CMDailyReport/~3/P9Aw3__Tm9M/bulk.csv">Bulk Deals</a></h4>
      <h5 class="itemposttime"></h5>
      <div class="itemcontent" name="decodeable"><div class="feedflare">
     <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:yIl2AUoC8zA">
      <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0">
     </a> 
     <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:F7zBnMyn0Lo">
      <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?i=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:F7zBnMyn0Lo" border="0">
     </a> 
     <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:qj6IDK7rITs">
      <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0">
     </a> 
     <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:gIN9vFwOqvQ">
      <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?i=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0">
     </a>
     </div>
      <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/nseindia/CMDailyReport/~4/P9Aw3__Tm9M" height="1" width="1" alt="">
     </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `$(".regularitem .itemtitle")`, you're getting the `<h4>` and not the link (`<a>`) that is inside it.

To get the "Bulk Deals", you can do the following in your browser (or click on the 'Run code snippet' button):

```js
var html = `<li xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" class="regularitem">
  <h4 class="itemtitle">
   <a href="http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/nseindia/CMDailyReport/~3/P9Aw3__Tm9M/bulk.csv">Bulk Deals</a></h4>
  <h5 class="itemposttime"></h5>
  <div class="itemcontent" name="decodeable"><div class="feedflare">
 <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:yIl2AUoC8zA">
  <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0">
 </a> 
 <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:F7zBnMyn0Lo">
  <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?i=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:F7zBnMyn0Lo" border="0">
 </a> 
 <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:qj6IDK7rITs">
  <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0">
 </a> 
 <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?a=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:gIN9vFwOqvQ">
  <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/nseindia/CMDailyReport?i=P9Aw3__Tm9M:Clpwmq7B-_I:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0">
 </a>
 </div>
  <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/nseindia/CMDailyReport/~4/P9Aw3__Tm9M" height="1" width="1" alt="">
 </div>
</li>`
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll(".regularitem .itemtitle")).forEach(function(h4) {
  var link = h4.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  console.log(link.innerHTML);
});
```

Hope it helps,

Best regards

Comment: This worked!! so do you suggest I use DOMParser along with 'request' and 'cheerio' to scrape the HTML code ?

Comment: I'm still struggling with that, because nodejs has no DOMParser object. There is a module `dom-parser` but it doesn't implement the `querySelectorAll` method, so it will be more difficult to parse the HTML

Comment: I was going to implement this in my setup and I just read DOMParser is not supported in Nodejs . Do you recommend this method or any alternative ? But this did get the data I wanted.

Comment: I'm recomend `jsdom`, that is (from my point of view) far better than cheerio

Comment: : thanks!! this kind of is a good start for me especially with respect to what tags to call.

Comment: Thanks!!  i'll look that up jsdom.  Am going to mark this as  the answer though. Because it did help me.

Comment: Thanks, I just had a look at the page you're trying to scrap and it looks complicated : the body of the request does not contain the whole HTML, I think that the HTML is build with the `xls` fils that is sent.
When pages are asynchronously loaded, it's better to use headless browsers or equivalent tools. My favorite one is nightmarejs (it's very simple to use and get the job done)